# Run bat file as admin without user knowing

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, service, cmd

I know the title seams a little bit shady, and there is a few question already but they does not quite answer my question.
I'm trying to make a self updating windows service. The problem is that the service will run in a background of a register, I don't want to user to be prompt to update the service. I'm currently trying to run a batch file as administrator without have to authorize it in the prompt window.

I'm using the `StartInfo.Verb = "runas"` 
Here is my code

```
private void RestartService()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = $"{Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)}\\assets\\renameAndRestart.bat";
        proc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
        proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        proc.Start();
    }
```

Comment: You cannot do this - it's exactly why UAT was invented - to make sure every action that needs administrator requirements needs user confirmation.

Comment: Tasks and services can run privileged without requiring consent every time they're started, but initially configuring them requires admin access.

Comment: that is why there are things like group policies.

Comment: @eryksun you can therefore also send enter to screen to do that for you, but let's rather not get into that :)

Comment: @GerhardBarnard, the default configuration displays the UAC consent dialog on the secure Winlogon Desktop. A program can't open and switch to that Desktop unless it's running as SYSTEM. Obviously an administrator can install a task or service that runs as SYSTEM, if that's what you meant, but that's as designed, not an elevation of privilege exploit.